# Spring Data: Obtain Target Class object and custom interface type for a Spring bean

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-aop

I have an app working with:

- `Spring Framework`
- `Spring Data JPA`

For Testing, through `JUnit` 5, I have the following:

```
@Autowired
private GodRepository godRepository;

....

@Test
void classTest() {
    logger.info("Target (AOP) Class: {}", AopUtils.getTargetClass(godRepository));
    logger.info("Target expepcted Type Class: {}", GodRepositoryDataJpaAdapter.class);
    assertThat(AopUtils.getTargetClass(godRepository)).isNotNull()
                                                      .isEqualTo(GodRepositoryDataJpaAdapter.class);
}
```

It works and passes. Here `GodRepositoryDataJpaAdapter` implements `GodRepository`.

**Purpose**: confirm that `@Autowired` injected really the `GodRepositoryDataJpaAdapter` class type in runtime, through the `GodRepository` type

Until here it is all ok and is about explicitly for `Spring Framework`

Now about `Spring Data`

Exists defined the following custom `interface`:

```
public interface GodRepositoryDataJpa extends CrudRepository<God, String> {

}
```

again for testing purposes

```
@Autowired
private CrudRepository<God, String> godCrudRepository;

...

@Test
void classTest() {
    logger.info("Target (AOP) Class: {}", AopUtils.getTargetClass(godCrudRepository));
    logger.info("Target (AOP) Class: {}", AopUtils.getTargetClass(godCrudRepository).getSuperclass());
    logger.info("Target expepcted Type Class: {}", GodRepositoryDataJpa.class);
}
```

It prints:

```
Target (AOP) Class: class org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository 
Target (AOP) Class: class java.lang.Object 
Target expepcted Type Class: interface com.manuel.jordan.repository.data.jpa.GodRepositoryDataJpa
```

Observe that for the first line was printed `SimpleJpaRepository`, it is the class generated behind the scenes by `Spring Data`

**Request**: how, if is possible, to retrieve in runtime the `GodRepositoryDataJpa` type (my custom `interface`) to accomplish later the assertion without any problem

**Note**: if I try:

```
logger.info("Target (AOP) Class: {}", Arrays.asList(AopUtils.getTargetClass(godCrudRepository).getAnnotatedInterfaces()));
logger.info("Target (AOP) Class: {}", Arrays.asList(AopUtils.getTargetClass(godCrudRepository).getAnnotatedSuperclass()));
```

I got:

```
Target (AOP) Class: [sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotatedTypeFactory$AnnotatedParameterizedTypeImpl@77a0dd63] 
Target (AOP) Class: [sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotatedTypeFactory$AnnotatedTypeBaseImpl@543fe698]
```

Comment: The question is technically interesting. I am sure it is helpful to understand the inner workings of Spring (Data) for an advanced developer. I am just curious to learn why you would write tests like these. They are just testing Spring, not really your application logic. So I assume your real intent is to find out something during runtime for another purpose (which one?) and the tests are just for illustration. I am not a Spring guy and will not answer your question, I just want to help you get answers by explaining your problem instead just describing your solution. :-)

Comment: I don't see any use case for this

Comment: I understand both points of view. Here the goal is test or confirm that the class generated by Spring Data and injected through `Autowired` explicitly belongs to the custom interface (`GodRepositoryDataJpa`) hierarchy. In this case is returning `SimpleJpaRepository`